# Determine Celltype of Datagridview in ProcessCmdKey/ProcessDialogKey VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Using a derived class, I capture the  key on a DataGridView and process it as a TAB key.  (No issue).

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As    System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Return Then
        keyData = Keys.Tab
        With msg
            .WParam = Keys.Tab
        End With
    End If

    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function

'
'This routine handles Cell Editing
Protected Overrides Function ProcessDialogKey(ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean

    If keyData = Keys.Return Then
        keyData = Keys.Tab
    End If

    Return MyBase.ProcessDialogKey(keyData)
End Function
```

But a situation has come up where I want to place a Button cell type into the row.  I don't want to process ENTER > TAB for that cell type.   I would prefer ENTER to work as ENTER.
I cannot find any example code to show me how to determine the CELLTYPE of the cell where I'm processing the keystroke.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you check the `TypeName` on the SelectedCells(0) cell?

Comment: I just tried doing a Me.Columns(CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).CellType Which seems to give me what I want...but I'm now trying to test that value with IS TYPEOF and doesn't seem to like it...(yet)

Comment: Dim dcl As DataGridViewCell = dgvSearch.SelectedCells(0)
        If TypeName(dcl) Is GetType(DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) Then

Comment: Close but not quite.   Typename returns a string.  Gettype returns a type.  Thus the test is now testing "DataGridViewButtonCell" IS  GETTYPE("System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewButtonCell") so it's not matching up....  I'm messing with my tests...but this isn't QUITE matching up unless I tested against a LITERAL.